# Save multiple results of array values from getValues for recall later in google script (Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm relatively new to scripting and I have spent hours getting myself to this point... so any help from here is much appreciated.

I am creating a sheets doc that calculates and generates quotes for a tradie friend of mine.
Each time He calculates a Quote on the Spreedsheet, I want to save all the data + recall it later.
On another occasion, he'll input new values into the cells & want to save all again, with a new quoteID and values, from the same spreadsheet.

Effectively, I need a saved copy of the values that can then be recalled by a particular ID later on if he wants to "regenerate" that quote..

Basically, I have an 3 arrays + 3 single cells that I want to get all values for (nailed this part)

```
// custom menu function
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Save Data','saveData')
      .addToUi();
}
// function to save data
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var writesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Saved Quotes");
  var houselabour = ss.getRange("Calculating the Quote!A7:B38").getValues();
  Logger.log(houselabour);
  var tradelabour = ss.getRange("Calculating the Quote!E7:F38").getValues();
  var materials = ss.getRange("Calculating the Quote!H7:K38").getValues();
  var quoteid = ss.getRange('Calculating the Quote!B2').getValue();
  var surname = ss.getRange('Calculating the Quote!B1').getValue();
  var datecreated = ss.getRange('Calculating the Quote!C2').getValue();

  var s1 = houselabour.toString();
  var s2 = tradelabour.toString();
  var s3 = materials.toString();
  writesheet.appendRow([quoteid,surname,datecreated,s1+s2+s3]);
}
//function to recall data
function recallData()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activequoteid = ss.getActiveCell("Customers").getValue();
  //input values from saved data (by quoteid) into Calculating the Quote Spreadsheet... ???
```

Ideally, I would input these values (quoteid, surname, datecreated) into a new sheet (writesheet) and then i've made the array data into string so i can input it into a single cell (this cell doesn't need to be read, just re-called to fill in the original table later)

Later on,  I want to recall the same values I originally extracted back into the original quote generator -  "Calculating the Quote" sheet.

2 things: Is it possible, instead of converting the 3 arrays I have to strings, to just log them somewhere  without necessarily displaying them in the sheet anywhere? It is essential that the code that runs on a dropdown menu selection "save data" saves the array data and then the next time it is run it does not overrride the original but saves as another

I have a few solutions in my head
1) name each result of the Save Data function something unique (saved as array)...
- i do not know how to do this!
- if i dont print it out anywhere, where does it go???

2) append a row on the save quotes spreadsheet with the string instead of array, then when recalling the data with a new function, convert the object from .getValues 
- i also do not know how to do this

... I also feel like there's a super easy solution to this that i'm just completely missing.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Narrow down your problem into just one question instead of your ```2 things```. In resume, Do you want to take some data from "Sheet A" into "sheet B"? Also, please share a Spreadsheet with some dummy data to visualize better what you are requesting.

Comment: 1. Use propertiesService or CacheService